# Optimize conditional operators branching in C#

Tags: c#, .net, boolean-logic, conditional-operator

return this.AllowChooseAny.Value ?
           radioSpecific.Checked ?
              UserManager.CurrentUser.IsClient ? txtSubject.Text : subjectDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text :
              String.Empty :
           UserManager.CurrentUser.IsClient ? txtSubject.Text : subjectDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;

or in less complex form:

```
return any ?
    specified ?
       isClient ? textbox : dropdown :
       empty :
    isClient ? textbox : dropdown;
```

or in schematic form:

```
                     |
                    any
              /            \
      specified             isClient
      /        \           /        \
  isClient    empty     textbox  dropdown
  /       \
textbox  dropdown
```

Evidently I have a duplicated block on two different levels. Is it possible to optimize this code to probably split them to one? Or something like that..

Comment: I would stab my eyes out with a fork if I ever ran into this.....

Comment: I love Resharper but it definitely looks like someone got a little too happy with replace with return there! And your comment @Matt made me bust out laughing at work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
any && !specified ? 
   empty : 
   isClient ? textbox : dropdown;
```

Answer (score 11):

That block of code is nearly unreadable. Don't use the ternary operator just for the sake of the ternary operator; it's there to make thigs *more* readable by eliminating `if` blocks for very simple expressions. What you have is not.

Comment: although i agree with you, you didn't answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

You can simplify your expression to this:

```
if (any && !specified)
{
    return empty;
}
else
{
    return isClient ? textbox : dropdown;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `isClient ? textbox : dropdown` block in a method and make method calls from you original branch = no more code duplication.